# MongoDB Atlas & Node JS - Architecture Layout

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Recently I have been considering using MongoDB Atlas for a deployment which is fairly heavy in the DB department and also on the Node.JS server side.

Whereas I am quite familiar with the normal NAT Gateway--> VPC layout on AWS, in all my research on Atlas I have been left terribly confused about some really important specifics.

I am incredibly confused as to how to implement a NodeJS server with MongoDB Atlas. If I set up my own NAT Gateway & VPC on AWS with all the servers, replicas, shards etc. then I know exactly where my entry point is, where my NodeJS server is on that zone and how to replicate etc. But if use this scenario then I lose all the comfort and time-saving which Atlas affords me, not to mention the headaches of scalability etc.

However, in all the Atlas documentation, I can only find how it sets up Atlas on a VPC. I cannot figure out, (maybe my brain cells are not working), where in all this configuration the Node server would go? Or can one set up a NAT Gateway and VPC and then place an Atlas controlled MongoDB setup behind it?

The architecture with Atlas has me confused. Where do you set up your servers so they are also secure? Do I need to create a second NAT Gateway and VPC just for my Node server app? If so do I require VPC peering?

If this is dumb, please excuse the question. But before I begin a setup which will cost the company a good deal of money, I need to be clear on exactly what the layout is.

Thanking all who can handle this question in advance as any and all pointers here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think you are confusing MongoDB Atlas for something it is not. "Deploy, operate, and scale a MongoDB database in the cloud with just a few clicks." It does not say anything about Node.js.

Comment: @str thanks but I am not confused. I know that. So I use Atlas. Where or where do I deploy a secure Node server in this layout??

Comment: By "Node server", you actually mean "Node.js server"? It does not matter at all. MongoDB Atlas is a DBaaS. You can connect to it from everywhere, your local machine, AWS, Google Apps, Azure, Heroku, ...

Comment: @str do I put the Node Server behind a NAT gateway of its own, in order to maintain security which is required here (seems a bit of overkill but maybe required). Do you have any suggestions from actual implementation? These suggestions are what I am looking for. Others who have implemented this. @ btw thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MongoDB Atlas**

You can create a VPC Peering Connection from MongoDB Atlas VPC to a VPC in your AWS account where you have your NodeJS EC2 instances running. Check the documentation [Introducing VPC Peering for MongoDB Atlas](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/introducing-vpc-peering-for-mongodb-atlas) for more details.

**Your Custom MongoDB Cluster**

Setting up MongoDB with best practices will require creating public and private subnets in the VPC while placing the database cluster in the private subnet. It will also involve having a NAT server in the public subnet for the MongoDB cluster to forward egress traffic keeping it secure within the VPC.

[image]
Reference: [AWS Quick Start for MongoDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiHl9.png)

However this can be challenging if you are new to AWS. To simplify the work use a AWS Quick Start for [AWS Quick Start for MongoDB](https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/mongodb/) which will create the required architecture with best practices.

After provisioning the MongoDB Cluster, you can provision a NodeJS Web Server using one of the following options,

- Using [Elastic Beanstalk](https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) to place the NodeJS Servers with AutoScaling and Load Balancing with Best Practices.
- Setup an Application Load Balancer, AutoScaling Group and NodeJS EC2 instance Launch Configuration inside the VPC to manually.
- Create a [EC2 template](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-ec2.html) (Newly introduced) with required configuration.
- Manually setup a server inside the VPC.

Note: If you place your NodeJS Web Servers in Private Subnet, make sure you create a public load balancer and configure the subdomains where NodeJS We Servers are allowed for load balancer as well so that it can route traffic to any subnet where the automated provisioning places the NodeJS Web Servers.

Comment: ty for that document, though I have already seen it. The question here is the option "Manually setup a server inside the VPC". Once I implement Atlas are you aware if I have access to that VPC to add a Node server?

Comment: You can setup a VPC Peering Connection between MongoDB Atlas and Your VPC where you have NodeJS servers. Check the updated answer.

Comment: exactly what I thought and put VPC Peering in my question. I assumed a VPC peering was required. Ty..answer seems to be on the mark!